# How to use rehydrated Kombu after making Dashi?

Tags: soup, japanese-cuisine, dashi, kombu

To prepare a Miso Soup the first step is the preparation of the Dashi.
The Dashi will most certainly contain Kombu. Can the rehydrated Kombu be used in the Miso? What kind of preparation does the rehydrated Kombu need, before consuming?
Is the Kombu actually used in Miso in Japan or other sea weeds (such as Wakame) are used?
Is there any other used of the rehydrated Kombu from the Dashi preparation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can](https://www.leaf.tv/articles/how-to-eat-kombu-seaweed/) chop it and eat it or add to your soup, stir fry, dry and crush into a powder to use as a condiment, etc.